# Drupal 8 get taxonomy value in twig

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

I'm working on Drupal 8,
I have a content type, called Home page, with fields of content and one field of type Entity Reference who is linked to a taxonomy item.
In page.html.twig I want to get the value of this taxonomy item.

I tried a lot of think but nothing works.

a read than I need to do this code:

```
{{node.field_home_page_slider_type}}
```

but it give me a white page. I tried with kint, I'have a lot of property but I dont found how to get the value of my field.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still struggling with twig, just prepare what you need in `your_theme.theme`. You can get your node in

```
function HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!array_key_exists('node', $variables))
    return;
  $node = $variables['node'];
  // ...
```

}

Here you can prepare your data and provide it for twig like this:

```
$variables['foo'] = 'bar';
```

In Twig you can do this:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i founded was to preprocess the node of the page to get the content of the taxonomy field.

Here a example of my code

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $field = 'title';
    $index = 0;
    if($node){
        $nodeArray = $node->toArray();
        if (isset($nodeArray[$field][$index]['value'])) {
            $value = $nodeArray[$field][$index]['value'];
        }
        if(isset($nodeArray['field_home_page_slider_type'])){
            $id_slider_type = $nodeArray['field_home_page_slider_type'][0]['target_id'];
        }
    }
```